# very simple regex code for a specific string

Tags: regex

I hate to ask specific question, but i need the regex code for matching strings like :

```
{block any_single_word_here}
    Anything Here
{/block}
```

Comment: Specific questions are _good_, but this is not a specific "question" per se: rather, it is a request for someone to do your coding for you.

Comment: i already tried this question myself about 100 times.

Comment: MY OWN CODE : /\{block ([^\}]+)\}([^\{]+)?\{\/block}/ , isn't working as expected :(

Comment: Define "isn't working as expected". This is still a localised request for support/help, rather than a question about a programming language.

Comment: BTW that regex looks pretty much okay, if a little extra-verbose. I believe `/{block (.+?)}(.+?){\/block}/` is pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Which regex engine? There are different flavours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original query is very close, albeit a little verbose. It can be shortened to:

```
/{block (.+?)}(.+?){\/block}/
```

(The `?` modifier stops the `+` from being "greedy", so you don't have to explicitly stop the match at the next `}` or `{`.)

Next you have to consider that `.` won't match newlines by default. You can change this with the `/s` flag:

```
/{block (.+?)}(.+?){\/block}/s
```

[Here's a demo.](http://www.ideone.com/yFTXY)

And here's [the documentation from `man perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

> **s**
>
> Treat string as single line. That is, change "`.`" to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Comment: **Note:** This answer pertains to Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions. You did not specify which engine you're using.

Comment: if you don't mind, then please improve this regex : `/\{\$?([^# ]+)\#?([^ ]+)? ?([^|]+)?[ \|]?([^\}]+)?\}/` :)

Comment: @Pawan: That's a separate question!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421443/regex-help-me-to-improve-my-existing-regex-code :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job?

`/\{block \w+\}\r?\n.*?\r?\n\{\/block\}/i`

Comment: nopes dude, and also you're missing "\" in front of `/block` word

Comment: In what flavor of regex are you required to escape a forward-slash? Ahh, when you use forward-slash as the delimiter. That's what I get for being fancy. :P There, all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript (added escape to end of lines in original string) I added a `\s*` (zero or more spaces) to your regex and it outputs a match for `any_single_word_here` and `Anything Here` fine...

```
alert( "{block any_single_word_here}\
    Anything Here\
{/block}".match(/\{block ([^\}]+)\}\s*([^\{]+)?\{\/block}/) )
```

For simpler regex, remove the unneccessary escaping, and just capture with `.` rather than complex `[^\}]`

```
/{block (.+)}\s*(.+){\/block}/
```

Comment: Why `\s*`? `.` can eat up whitespace.

Comment: because I expect `Anything Here` is the desired value, and has newline and spaces before for formatting reasons only, so this might be causing the "unexpected results".

Comment: OK, that's reasonable. But if so we'd need _far_ more information on what the OP calls "expected" to provide a fix that will cover all his cases.

Comment: agreed - the question is not specific enough to give a specific answer