# help me to improve my existing regex code

Tags: regex

I'm using this 
`/\{\$?([^# ]+)\#?([^ ]+)? ?([^|]+)?[ \|]?([^\}]+)?\}/`
 perl-compatible regular expression
For matching strings like : 
`{$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? |ucfirst|strtoupper}`

Outputting this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => {$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? |ucfirst|strtoupper}
    [1] => string
    [2] => asdf#asdf
    [3] => can you hear me? 
    [4] => ucfirst|strtoupper
)
```

if used with `PHP's preg_replace_callback` function,

but with string like `{$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? ucfirst|strtoupper}` it's outputting this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => {$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? ucfirst|strtoupper}
    [1] => string
    [2] => asdf#asdf
    [3] => can you hear me? ucfirst
    [4] => strtoupper
)
```

can you improve it the way you wish so that it will be able to match string like : 
`{$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? ucfirst|strtoupper}` (notice: "|" removed in front of ucfirst) without affecting the result of the array.
(ie output should be the same as the first printed array above)

Answer (score 0):

This Regex string already matches both of the samples you provided. What are you really asking here?

[image]

Comment: What tool is that screenshot from?

Comment: It's from [this website](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), I don't know what the name of the tool is, but it is *incredibly* helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear exactly what you're wanting, but here's my best guess based on what you specified:

```
{\$([^#]*)#(\S*) (.*?) (\S*)}
```

That will give the following for matches 1-4

1. Everything up to the first # sign
2. Everything after the first # sign and before the next space
3. Everything else between #2 and #4
4. The last string of characters not containing a space

In the example

```
{$string#asdf#asdf can you hear me? ucfirst|strtoupper}
```

We have:

1. string
2. asdf#asdf
3. can you hear me?
4. ucfirst|strtoupper